# Calculate a 4 by 4 matrix and display sum of all elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to code a 4 by 4 matrix and sum all of the matrix. Here is the code i made in c++.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int size = 4;
    int sum, i, j;
    int SumMatrix[4][4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a  by 4 matrix row by row: \n";
        cin >> i;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            cout << "\n";
            cin >> j;

        }
    }
    sum += SumMatrix[i][j];
    cout << "Sum of the matrix is" << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled the code, it shows that it has no errors. But when I execute it, 
[it gave me this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL9JC.png)

Please help. I'm a noob and i'm stuck. I don't know any other alternative to solve this.

Comment: What do you expect `sum += SumMatrix[i][j];` to do?

Comment: 1) Change `cin >> j;`, don't use the same variable used by for loop. 2) Put the value you read into `SumMatrix`. 3) Move `sum += SumMatrix[i][j];` inside the loops right after the (2). Btw you should probably remove this `cin >> i;` and move `cout << "Enter a  by 4 matrix row by row: \n";` before the loops.

Comment: One more thing change `int sum` to `int sum = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

> When I compiled the code, it shows that it has no errors. But when I execute it, it gave me this error.

That's because your program has no `syntax errors` but encounters `runtime error(s)`.

Now, focus on the outer loop (`for(i...)`). You have written the statement

```
cin >> i;
```

Note, `i` is the loop control variable. So when you enter the first element of the first row, it actually gets into `i` and thus the loop gets totally messed up. (*You may be getting an `array index out of bounds` error here.*) So what you have to do is modify the the entire nested loop structure into this:

```
for(i = 0; i<4; i++){
    for(j=0; j<4; j++){
        cin >> SumMatrix[i][j];
        sum += SumMatrix[i][j]; //adding up the elements
   }
}
/*the array now has all the elements
  and sum stores the value of sum of all elements*/
```

Basically, you were trying to read elements into an array but were unacquainted with the correct syntax. `i` and `j` do not directly refer to the elements at row i and column j; the correct syntax to access an array element at row i and column j is `SumMatrix[i][j]`.

Also, note that the statement

```
sum += SumMatrix[i][j];
```

**as written in your code**, which is outside the loop, only adds the last element of the array to the sum. In order to get the sum of all elements, you have to do it in a loop as I've shown above.

Answer (score -1):

This statement in the inner loop

```
cin >> j;
```

does not make sense. You have to enter elements of the matrix instead of changing the index.

Also this statement

```
sum += SumMatrix[i][j];
```

must be enclosed in loops.

And you have to initialize initially the variable `sum` to 0.

And the variables `i` and `j` also were not initialized

```
int sum, i, j;
         ^^^^^
```

Thus this statement

```
sum += SumMatrix[i][j];
```

results in undefined behavior of the program.

You should remove their declaration  because they should be declared and used in loops.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 4;
    int matrix[N][N] = {};

    std::cout << "Enter a " << N << " by " << N << " matrix row by row: \n";

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter row " << i << ": ";
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) std::cin >> matrix[i][j];
    }

    long long int sum = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) sum += matrix[i][j];
    }

    std::cout << "Sum of the matrix is " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a 4 by 4 matrix row by row: 
Enter row 0: 1 2 3 4
Enter row 1: 5 6 7 8
Enter row 2: 9 10 11 12
Enter row 3: 13 14 15 16
Sum of the matrix is 136
```

To calculate the sum you could use also standard algorithm `std::accumulate` that in turn uses `std::accumulate` for each row.

Comment: Why 4 loops? Just calculate the `sum` in the first 2 loops.

Comment: @DimChtz I try not to show a bad code. With four loops the logic of the program is transparent and the program itself can be split into functions or can use standard algorithms.